# How do I update the CSS for the current slide in the Slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a site to showcase my client's photography. I have several different main images that rotate in a slideshow. I want the link to that specific category to change to a different color when it's corresponding image is shown. My function works perfectly for the 1st image but it won't work for my second one. Can someone read my code and see what may be wrong? I'm not getting any errors in the console and I believe it should work since it's literally the same function as the first one. Thank you so much!!

```
<!-- Photo Slider -->
        <div id="maincarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid natureMain" src="bppnature/Hope.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid buildingMain" src="bppbuildings/here comes the sun (around the way).jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid fashionMain" src="bppfashion/Eye Eternal.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid productMain" src="Main Images/Proper Prepardness.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid abstractMain" src="bppabstract/Interconnected.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid coverMain" src="bppcoverart/Black EGYptian BastARD (right).jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid graffittiMain" src="bppgraffitti/Gang'N'em.jpg">
            </div>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
              </ol>
          </div>
        </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
                // $("#mainslider").slick({
                //   infinite: true,
                //   slidesToShow: 1,
                //   slidesToScroll: 1,
                //   centerMode: true,
                // //   autoplay: true,
                // //   autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                //   pauseOnHover: true
                // });
                highlightNatureMain();
                highlightBuildingMain();
                $('.slickcarousel').slick({
                  infinite: true,
                  slidesToShow: 4,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
                  centerMode: true,
                //   autoplay: true,
                //   autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                  pauseOnHover: true
                });
                carouselDisplay();
                // animationNature();
                // animationBuilding();
                // animationFashion();
                // animationProducts();
                // animationAbstract();
                // animationCovers();
                // animationGraffiti();
                // animationProjects();
                // stopHover();
                // imageHover();
                setInterval(function(){ nameFlash();}, 3000);

            });

function highlightNatureMain() {
                if ($(".natureMain").parent("div").hasClass("active")) {
                    $('.nav-nature').css('color', 'purple');
                }
                else {
                    $(".nav-nature").css("color","white");
                }
            }
            function highlightBuildingMain() {
                if ($(".buildingMain").parent("div").hasClass("active")) {
                    console.log("br");
                    $('.nav-building').css('color', 'purple');
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is `$('.slickcarousel').slick` a function?

Comment: Did you try printing something you can see to the console in `highlightBuildingMain`, instead of `<br>`, so you can see whether or not your function is even being called? Also, are you sure the `<div class="item">` element is getting the `active` class added - did you check in the browsers element inspector?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev that is a function from a plugin..

Comment: create a snippet where issue can be replicated.

Comment: @FluffyKitten im sure the div is getting active I checked it in the console...but i'll check and see if the function is being called that's a good idea

Comment: @FluffyKitten just checked...it's not being called. Is there any reason it wouldn't be called?

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason. Did you put the console.log before the `if ($(".buildingMain").parent("div").hasClass("active"))` or inside it? If you put it  before the if, then the function isn't being called, but if you put it inside the if the function might be getting called but the if condition is not being met... which brings me back to the `active` class. The reason is works for the first one is because you have explicitly added `active` to that element, which is why I'm still leaning towards that class being the issue somehow.

Comment: @FluffyKitten yeah I put it before the if...I just got the function to get called but it's not changing the style =(

Comment: @FluffyKitten I think I figured out the problem but not necessarily the solution lol I think it's only running when the page loads...do you know of a way to make it keep running? Or rerun constantly?

Comment: What is it that you want it to do exactly? For example, do you want to change the css for the slide each time a new slide appears?

Comment: @FluffyKitten yes I want to change the CSS of my menu links so it's a different color depending on the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the CSS on the slides, you are over-complicating things - you don't need javascript at all!

**CSS-only**

You already have classes associated with your slides, so you just need to create rules for those classes, e.g.

```
.item .nav-nature{ color: purple;}    /* default colour for this element */
.item.active .nav-nature{ color: white;}    /* colour when this item is active */
.item .nav-building{ color: purple;}
.item.active .nav-nature{ color: white;}
```

**jQuery Callback functions for Slick slider**

However if you did need to do something in jQuery, slick slider has callback functions `beforeChange` and `afterChange`, so you could use those, e.g.

```
jQuery('#mainslider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

    switch(nextSlide){
        case 1: /* next slide is the first slide */
           [... do something...]
           break;
        case 2: /* second slide */
           [...]
           break;
    }
}
```

**Use Callback to set link colour**

If you do need to set the CSS for the links through jQuery, a handy way to do it is to use an array for the colours - the `currentSlide` and `nextSlide` are the slide positions, so you can use them as the key to the array, e.g.

CSS - set the default colours for the links

```
.item .nav-nature{ color: purple;} 
.item .nav-building{ color: purple;}
```

jQuery - set the colour for the active slide

```
/* an array of the link colours, corresponding to the slides */
var linkcolours = ["white", "white", "blue", "red", etc...];

jQuery('#mainslider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    /* set the active slide colour to the position of the corresponding slide 
       e.g. get the 1st element from the array (index=0) for slide 1 etc */
    $(".item.active a").css("color", colours[nextSlide-1]);
});
```