# Is there a way to call a function everytime a bootstrap carousel slides to a different image?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a site to showcase my client's photography. I have several different main images that rotate in a slideshow. I want the link to that specific category to change to a different color when it's corresponding image is shown.

My function works perfectly for the 1st image but it won't work for my second one because it only calls the function when the page loads. Is there a way I can make it recheck my functions once the carousel goes to a different slide? Thank you in advance =)

```
<!-- Photo Slider -->
        <div id="maincarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid natureMain" src="bppnature/Hope.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid buildingMain" src="bppbuildings/here comes the sun (around the way).jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid fashionMain" src="bppfashion/Eye Eternal.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid productMain" src="Main Images/Proper Prepardness.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid abstractMain" src="bppabstract/Interconnected.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid coverMain" src="bppcoverart/Black EGYptian BastARD (right).jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid graffittiMain" src="bppgraffitti/Gang'N'em.jpg">
            </div>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                <li data-target="#maincarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
              </ol>
          </div>
        </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
                // $("#mainslider").slick({
                //   infinite: true,
                //   slidesToShow: 1,
                //   slidesToScroll: 1,
                //   centerMode: true,
                // //   autoplay: true,
                // //   autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                //   pauseOnHover: true
                // });
                highlightNatureMain();
                highlightBuildingMain();
                $('.slickcarousel').slick({
                  infinite: true,
                  slidesToShow: 4,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
                  centerMode: true,
                //   autoplay: true,
                //   autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                  pauseOnHover: true
                });
                carouselDisplay();
                // animationNature();
                // animationBuilding();
                // animationFashion();
                // animationProducts();
                // animationAbstract();
                // animationCovers();
                // animationGraffiti();
                // animationProjects();
                // stopHover();
                // imageHover();
                setInterval(function(){ nameFlash();}, 3000);

            });

function highlightNatureMain() {
                if ($(".natureMain").parent("div").hasClass("active")) {
                    $('.nav-nature').css('color', 'purple');
                }
                else {
                    $(".nav-nature").css("color","white");
                }
            }
            function highlightBuildingMain() {
                if ($(".buildingMain").parent("div").hasClass("active")) {
                    console.log("br");
                    $('.nav-building').css('color', 'purple');
                }
            }
```

Comment: Subscribe to the [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events) - the events are the same in Bootstrap 3 and 4, so you can just refer to the BS4 docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't jQuery highlight my link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355600/why-wont-jquery-highlight-my-link)

Comment: Its against Stack Overflow guidelines to create a duplicate question - you should just update your existing one! As I've answered on your other question from 2 hours ago, you don't need jQuery, you can do this in CSS. But if you need to use jQuery for something else, you can use the `beforeChange` or `afterChange` callback functions for slick slider: [See answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355600/how-do-i-update-the-css-for-the-current-slide-in-the-slick-carousel/46356924#46356924)

Comment: @FluffyKitten sorry didn't know but thank you for all your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. According to [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events) you can use the events `slide.bs.carousel` when the slide is about to change and `slid.bs.carousel` after is has changed.

Here is an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel_event_slide&stacked=h).

Here's the important code you need

```
$("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    alert('A new slide is about to be shown!');
});
```

**EDIT:**
In the title, you mention Bootstrap carousel but in your code you're using slick slider. Which slider do you want to use?

The logic is the same. Just subscribe to the event.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap for this specific carousel but I'm using slick for a different one...thank you too! I got the function to call repeatedly  but for some reason it's highlighting the link after the slide has already changed to the next one

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function inside this function:

```js
$("#your-carousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  // call your function here
});
```

Visit https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel_event_slide&stacked=h